# understanding hardhat JSON-RPC url - when is it used by DAPP?

Tags: evm, json-rpc, hardhat, hardhat-deploy, full-node

I have a react.js app running using [Portis](https://portis.com) wallet and I deployed one of my smart contracts using hardhat, using the url obtained from pokt.network and the other from default public url: https://rpc.gnosischain.com/ (as pokt url had timeout error). when I see network tab in my browser I see the portis wallet is using https://dai.poa.network/ as RPC url.

My question is, where does my app get the JSON-RPC url from to communicate to the node? how to customize it?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the Portis wallet. But you can customize the RPC URL by navigating to the Networks tab in settings.

See Chainlist.org to easily import the chain.